# vim indentation with Rails for conditional validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I'm using Tim Pope's vim-rails bundle.  In a model with a conditional validation, vim is breaking "normal" indentation.

I see this:

```
validates_presence_of :terms_agreement, unless: :guest?
                                        validates_presence_of :rules_agreement, unless: :guest?

                                                                                  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

                                                                                  def active_for_authentication?
                                                                                    super && !self.disabled?
                                                                                  end
```

Where I would expect to see this:

```
validates_presence_of :terms_agreement, unless: :guest?
validates_presence_of :rules_agreement, unless: :guest?

accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

def active_for_authentication?
  super && !self.disabled?
end
```

If there's no condition indentation functions correctly but that little `unless` is kicking my butt. I know that environments vary wildly but any hints or tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using old hash syntax works fine.

```
validates_presence_of :terms_agreement, :unless => :guest?
validates_presence_of :rules_agreement, :unless => :guest?
```

What version of the vim-rails bundle do you have? looks like the new syntax support is added only in the newer versions. Try updating the bundle

Comment: rails.vim 5.0, still no joy - and here I've been working so hard to train myself to use newer syntax. Darn.  Oh well, thanks, this will get me by.

Comment: Try sleuth.vim. Release notes for 5.0 says "Indent settings are no longer automatically adjusted.  Try sleuth.vim. "